# Assigning Values inside an array

Tags: php

can someone explain this to me:

```
$a = array( $b1 = "b1", $b2 = "b2", array($b3 = "b3", $b4 = "b4"));

echo $$$$$a[2][1];
```

Why is this legal? The output is still "b4" even echoing `$a[2][1]`, `$$a[2][1]`, `$$$[2][1]` and so on.

What I expect is it will look for a variable "b4" if echoing `$a[2][1]` but it's still echoing the string "b4".

Thanks

Comment: @Ascherer Agreed. Makes my eyes bleed. Somewhere a single tear just rolled down an angel's cheek.

Answer (score 6):

Basically what is happening here is that you're declaring the $b* variables as you're adding them to the array. Your code above is equivalent to

```
Array("b1","b2", Array("b3", "b4"));
```

Which in turn is equivalent to

```
Array(0 => "b1", 1 => "b2", 2 => Array(0 => "b3", 1 => "b4"));
```

The second array is effectively includes the array indices which Php adds by default where an index is not defined.

When you input

```
Array($b1 = "b1");
```

the

```
$b1 = "b1"
```

is evaluated as "b1" prior to insertion in the array.

Answer (score 6):

```
$a = array( $b1 = "b1", $b2 = "b2", array($b3 = "b3", $b4 = "b4"));
```

In your array, you are not setting any keys.  You are setting values to the variables `$b1`, `$b2`, `$b3`, and `$b4` and then using those values in a (numeric) array.

So, `$b4 = "b4"`.  This sets `$b4` to the string `"b4"`, and then adds it to the array.

`$a[2][1]` is the string `"b4"`, so `$$a[2][1]` is the value of `$b4` which is `"b4"`, which makes `$$$a[2][1]` also `"b4"`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The result of assigning a value to a variable is the value itself. Therefore the above expression has side effects, but without those side effects, it could be written as:

```
$a = array( "b1", "b2", array("b3", "b4"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just be using the wrong operator for what you are trying to do. => is used to set keys in an array.

The = works for the same reason this line works:

```
if ($b1 = 'foo') {
    echo $b1; // prints foo
}
```

The assignment operator (=) returns the value.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing confusing about this. Inside the array you have `$b4 = "b4"`. Double dollar means, get the string and access the variable by that name, which is again "b4"